# Dealing with objects without interfaces in PHP8

Tags: php

PHP has the possibility to define interfaces as well as abstract classes for classes. However, it is not possible to define interfaces for objects, as in Typescript.

Therefore, the question I have is how best to deal with objects in PHP. Is there an alternative to Object interfaces?

Example:
A function that creates a new instance of the class `Filter`.
I need to check if the needed keys exist and check if their types are correct.

```
function createFilter(array $options): Filter|false
{
    $property = null; // string | array
    if (array_key_exists('property', $options) && (is_string($options['property']) || is_array($options['property']))) {
        $property = $options['property'];
    }
    $type = null; // string
    if (array_key_exists('type', $options) && is_string($options['type'])) {
        $type = $options['type'];
    }
    $value = null; // float
    if (array_key_exists('value', $options) && is_float($options['value'])) {
        $value = $options['value'];
    }
    if ($property === null || $type === null || $value === null) return false;
    return new Filter($property, $type, $value);
}
```

At the end of the function, I see two possibilities:

- Return False if the filter could not be created.
- return the class instance if the filter could be created

or:

- Always return the class instance. However, default values would then be used for the values that were not correctly created in `$options`

As said, currently there are no object interfaces in PHP. What is the current state of the art on how to best solve the above problem in **PHP8**?

Edit: Typescript

```
type FilterOptions = {
    property: string|string[],
    filterType: string,
    value: number
}

class Filter{
    constructor(property: string|string[], filterType: string, value: number){
        // ...
    }
}

const createFilter = (options : FilterOptions) : Filter => {
    return new Filter(options.property, options.filterType, options.value);
}
```

Comment: What is the exact TS interface feature you are missing? How would you implement the above in TS?

Comment: Added the example in ts to the question.

Comment: Why don't you just create a (base) class `FilterOptions` then and pass that instead of an array?

Comment: Yes, that was my question. Would you always use classes instead of object interfaces in PHP?

Comment: Well you could define an interface `IFilterOptions` as well and do `function foo(IFilterOptions $options)` which would accept any class which implements `IFilterOptions`. I guess it would depend on the situation. This would be more usefull if you had multiple types of filters, e.g. `ProductFilterOptions`, `BlogFilterOptions`, etc.